# How to generate combinations from char array?

Tags: java, algorithm, char, combinations

How to generate combinations from char array?
here is my code
https://anotepad.com/notes/icjsc5ct
I have an array with 5 characters: a, b, c, d, e
And I want to generate combinations of 3 characters

1. [a, b, c];
2. [a, b, d];
3. [b, c, d];
4. [b, c, e];
5. [c, d, e]

My code just can generate 2 combinations of 3 character:

1. [a, b, c];
2. [a, b, d];

I don't know how to increase index of Array[0] and Array[1];

````
public ArrayList< char[] > generate02( int r ) {

    ArrayList< char[] > combinationsList = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] data = new char[ r ];
    // initialize with lowest lexicographic combination
    for ( int i = 0; i < r; i++ ) {
        data[ i ] = CharArray01[ i ];
    }
    PrintData( CharArray01 );
    int n = CharArray01.length;
    while ( IndexInt( data[ r - 1 ] ) < n - 1 ) {
        int t01 = r - 1;
        System.out.println( " IndexInt( data[ r - 1 ] ) < n " );
        System.out.println( " data[ r - 1 ] ) = " + data[ t01 ]
                + ";  IndexInt( data[ r - 1 ] ) = "
                + IndexInt( data[ r - 1 ] )
                + ";  n = " + n );
        combinationsList.add( data.clone() );
        // generate next combination in lexicographic order
        int t02 = n - r + t01;
        while ( t01 != 0 && IndexInt( data[ t01 ] ) == t02 ) {
            t01--;
        }
        int k1 = IndexInt( data[ r - 1 ] );
        int k2 = k1 + 1;
        data[ r - 1 ] = IndexChar( k2 );
        System.out.println( " data[ r - 1 ] ) = " + data[ t01 ]
                + ";  IndexInt( data[ r - 1 ] ) = "
                + IndexInt( data[ r - 1 ] ) );
        System.out.println( "t01 = " + t01 + ";  n = " + n );
        int i = 0;
        for ( i = t01 + 1; i < r; i++ ) {
            int index02 = IndexInt( data[ i - 1 ] );
            int index03 = index02 + 1;
            data[ i ] = data[ index03 ];
        }
    }
    return combinationsList;
}
```
````

- Function PrintData convert a char array into String and Display it for my debug

  ```
  public void PrintData( char[] CharArray02 ) {
      int length = CharArray02.length;
      String string01 = "";
      for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
          string01 = string01 + CharArray02[ i ] + "  ";
      }
      System.out.println( "PrintData:  String01 = " + string01 );
  }
  ```
- Function IndexInt return position of char (start from 0) in sample string "abcde"

  ```
  public int IndexInt( char char01 ) {
      int result = 0;
      String string01 = "abcde";
      int length = string01.length();
      for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
          if ( char01 == (char) string01.charAt( i ) ) { return i; }
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```
- Function IndexChar return char at int position in sample string "abcde"

  ```
  public char IndexChar( int index01 ) {
      char result = 'a';
      String string01 = "abcde";
      result = string01.charAt( index01 );
      return result;
  }
  ```
- Function `public ArrayList<char[]> generate02(int r)` is the copy and modified code from algorithm integer combination. I really don't understand how the algorithm work

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code nicely formatted here. While you are at it, add more information about what exactly you are asking, e.g. where you are stuck, what your current code does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: Information on how to format your question can be found in the [help] under [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the solution/example you are are looking for I can refer you to an API I have created to generate combinations of objects in a memory efficient way: https://github.com/3venthorizon/meta/blob/master/meta-mathics/src/main/java/com/devlambda/meta/mathics/CombinationGenerator.java

```
@Test
public void charComboTest() {
   List<Character> domain = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
   CombinationGenerator<Character> combinations = new CombinationGenerator<>(domain, 3);
   while (combinations.hasNext()) {
      List<Character> combination = combinations.next();
      System.out.println(combination.stream().map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")));
   }
}
```

This prints out the the following result:

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
[a, b, e]
[a, c, d]
[a, c, e]
[a, d, e]
[b, c, d]
[b, c, e]
[b, d, e]
[c, d, e]
```